# How to use Obj-C classes in MacRuby

Tags: objective-c, macruby

I am trying to use an external Obj-C class in my MacRuby project, but I can't figure out how to import it. Specifically, I want to use ObjectiveResource inside a MacRuby 0.5 project (since ActiveResource doesn't work - yet).

I have gotten as far as the 'framework' command in MacRuby, but it only seems to apply to actual frameworks.

Questions: where should I install the objective-resource directory? how do I pull these classes inside my ruby code?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You can access the class directly using ClassName.new.

If you have a class named Utilities in your project and it has a method named greeting:, you would call it like so.

```
util = Utilities.new
puts util.greeting("Good morning")
```

There is no require or framework declarations required. Amazingly simple isn't it. I discovered this watching the [Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-macruby) screencast on MacRuby.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you are interested in calling Ruby code from Objective-c, here is an extract from the MacRuby mailing list:

Once the MacRuby runtime is initialized, you can access all your Objective-C objects from Ruby. For example, if you have an Objective-C class named Foo, you can do `Foo.new', etc.

Another possibility is to pass your Objective-C objects to a Ruby method by using `[NSObject performRubySelector:]`.

ruby:

```ruby
class Foo
  def test(o)
    o.something
  end
end
```

objc:

```objc
MyObject *o = [MyObject new]; // where o responds to -something
MacRuby *runtime = [MacRuby sharedRuntime]; 
id foo_obj = [runtime evaluateString:@"new Foo"];
[foo_obj performRubySelector:@selector(test:) withArguments: o, NULL];
```

Check out the whole API here: http://www.macruby.org/trac/browser/MacRuby/trunk/include/ruby/objc.h

Thread: http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macruby-devel/2010-April/004715.html

(Edit) That said, perhaps the easiest way is to add a header file for your ruby file, containing your methods equivalents.

Suppose that you have this ruby class:

```ruby
class Foo
  def bar(moo)
    "a string like #{moo}"
  end
end
```

so the equivalent header file will be something like that:

```objc
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (NSString *)bar:(NSString *)moo
@end
```

Now, just `#import` the header and use your ruby classes as standard Obj-C ones from within your Obj-C code:

```objc
NSString *aString;
Foo *myFoo;
aString = [myFoo bar:@"me"];
```

It may seem weird, but it works. Essentially, the idea is to shut the compiler's mouth and let it compile your code without complaining about missing methods. Then, at runtime, it will just work (I suppose thanks to the dynamic nature of Obj-C itself). By the way, to mimic the ruby typeless behavior, id is your friend in writing methods signatures in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [this](http://www.macruby.org/recipes/create-an-objective-c-bundle.html) example of creating an ObjC bundle?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but I doesn't work at all for me. I did get a little closer by creating a bundle manually according to this (http://www.mail-archive.com/macruby-devel@lists.macosforge.org/msg00940.html) example, but it is a very painful process and I haven't quite gotten it to work. I suppose the ObjectiveResource code (intended for iPhone apps) isn't all that suitable for this?

Comment: What errors do you get when you try the bundle? Can you edit your post to include the error messages?